# real analysis sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I am really struggling with this question:

$(a_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence such that

$$a_{n} < 1 \ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$

show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_{n} = 3$ is false by assuming by contradiction that $a_{n} \to 3$

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with $\epsilon$ proofs in the context of a limit as $n$ approaches $\infty$?  What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Take the short [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how how to get the most from your time here. For typesetting equations please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: If $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=3$ then for any $ r>0$ the set $S(r)=\{n\in \Bbb N: |a_n-3|\ge r\}$ is finite. But $S(1)=\Bbb N.$

Answer (score 1):

If $a_n\to 3$, then $a_n$ can be made arbitrarily close to $3$ by making $n$ sufficiently large. Do you see a problem with this given that $a_n<1$ for all $n$? Try to make this idea into a formal proof.